# Have memory error when using scipy to do SVD

Tags: python, scipy, svd

I tried to use LSI to generate vectors to represent documents. I am using the svd package in Scipy library. But the program throws a memory error. The size of my matrix is 100*13057. Is this too big for my 8G RAM?

I searched this problem in stackflow. Somebody said I just have to install 64-bit Python on my 64-bit OS. (Now, I have 32-bit Python on 64-bit OS). But re-installing all libraries is too trivial. Another opinion is to convert sparse matrix.

So does everyone have idea on this problem? Thanks!

```
raw_matrix = []
for text in forest_lsi:
    raw_matrix.append( text.get_vector() )
from svd import compute_svd
print("The size of raw matrix: "+str(len(raw_matrix))+" * "+str(len(raw_matrix[0])))
matrix = compute_svd( raw_matrix )
```

The message in Concole is as bellow:

```
The size of raw matrix: 100 * 13057
Original matrix:
[[1 1 2 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 3 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 ..., 1 1 3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace\PyQuEST\src\Practice\baseline_lsi.py", line 93, in <module>
    matrix = compute_svd( raw_matrix )
  File "D:\workspace\PyQuEST\src\Practice\svd.py", line 12, in compute_svd
    U, s, V = linalg.svd( matrix )
  File "D:\Program\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_svd.py", line 79, in svd
    full_matrices=full_matrices, overwrite_a = overwrite_a)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `V` matrix will take `13057*13057*8` bytes of memory if you're using the default `dtype=np.float`, which is approx. 1.4GB. My hunch is that that's too large for your 32-bit Python. Try using 32-bit floating point numbers, that is `dtype=np.float32`, to cut memory use in half, or start using `scipy.sparse` (almost always a good idea for information retrieval problems).

Comment: Thanks! 
I do it like this:
    from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix <br/>
    dok = dok_matrix(raw_matrix)   <br/>
    matrix = compute_svd( dok )   <br/>
I get another exception.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): <br/>
    File "D:\workspace\PyQuEST\src\Practice\baseline_lsi.py", line 96, in <module>     <br/>
        matrix = compute_svd( dok )     <br/>
    File "D:\workspace\PyQuEST\src\Practice\svd.py", line 12, in compute_svd     <br/>
        U, s, V = linalg.svd( matrix )     <br/>
    File "D:\Program\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_svd.py", line 79, in svd
    full_matrices=full_matrices, overwrite_a = overwrite_a)     <br/>
    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: @ChongWang: `scipy.linalg.svd` doesn't magically work with `scipy.sparse` matrices. Try `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`.

Comment: I still meet an exception when using scipy.sparse. I have opened a new question. I hope you can help me, Larsmans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650014/sparse-matrix-valueerror-matrix-type-must-be-f-d-f-or-d